# How to pass on modes with my Particle Emitter?

Tags: java, processing

`Mode` is a class that is used to give the `Particle` behaviours such as movement, colouration and reactions to other neighbouring `Particles`. `Particles` are used as reference points in space to build objects on the canvas. I took the decision to try `Modes` as a class that can be added to the `Particle` as needed. Partly because I want to keep the main `Particle` class as slim as possible, also because in the future I want `Particles` to be able to pass on `Modes` to each other. `Particles` are multi-purpose things, and it’s not appropriate to make sub-classes of `Particles`, as I believe this will restrict their use. They need to be able to change their behaviour, mutate and become strange through the acquisition of unique combinations of `Modes`.

`ParticleManager` extends `Particle`. It also will have its own kind of `Modes` so that behaviours can be applied to children `Particles`.
`ParticleManager` emits `Particles`. When it does this, it should pass on its own `Particle` `Modes` in `modes`.

Perhaps it is the Particle class itself that needs to be cloned/copied? However: if I make a copy constructor of `Particle` I am still left with the same problem with `Modes`.

I have some idea that `clone()` should be avoided. I haven’t seen any questions on SO about implementing this for more than one sub-class as below:

```
class Particle
{
  ArrayList<Mode>modes;
  Particle()
  {
    modes = new ArrayList<Mode>();
  }

  void update()
  {
    for (Mode m : modes)
    {
      m.apply();
    }
  }
}

class Mode 
{
  Mode(Particle p)
  {
    p.modes.add(this);
  }
  void apply()
  {
    //do something
  }

  Mode copy(Particle p)
  {

 ///of course this is wrong!
    return this;
  }
}


class ModeA extends Mode
{
  float transparency;
  ModeA(Particle p)
  {
    super(p);
  }
  void apply()
  {
    ///example
    transparency = random(1);
  }
}

class ModeB extends Mode
{
  int count;
  ModeB(Particle p)
  {
    super(p);
  }
  void apply()
  {
    ///example, but each mode is unique
    count++;
  }
}

class ParticleManager extends Particle
{
  ArrayList<Particle> particles;
  ArrayList<Mode> manager_modes;

  ParticleManager()
  {
    super();
    particles = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    manager_modes = new ArrayList<Mode>();
  }

  void emit()
  {
    ///make new particles that share the same
    ///modes as the parent
    Particle p = new Particle();

    for (Mode m : modes)
    {
      ////code here that duplicates the modes from
      ////the ParticleManagers modes into p.modes
      Mode m2 = m.copy(p);///obviously this doesn’t work!


    }
    particles.add(p);
  }

  void update()
  {

    for (Particle p : particles)
    {
      p.update();
    }
  }
}

ParticleManager pm; 

void setup()
{
  pm = new ParticleManager(); 
  ///adds the modes to the manager
  ModeA mA = new ModeA(pm); 
  ModeB mB = new ModeB(pm); 

  for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
    pm.emit();
  }
}

void draw()
{
  pm.update();
}
```

The solution needs to run as quickly as possible because it will be working on live visuals, although it is unlikely to be running every frame, of course.

Comment: First of all : why does your `ParticleManager` extends `Particle` since it contains several particules? It means that you could say _a Particle Manager is a Particle_.

Comment: @Ricola — A `ParticleManager` is a `Particle` because in future, they will be treated as `Particles` by a `GlobalParticleManager`. `ParticleManager` is a `Particle` so that it may behave like a `Particle`.
Let’s say that I want to make arrage the `Particles` into a cube, but then I want to move the cube around. This is done with the `ParticleManager`. Cube interacting with cube? `GlobalParticleManager`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're actually asking here. What's your question? What have you tried so far, and why hasn't that worked?

Comment: @KevinWorkman When `ParticleManager` emits, I want to clone/copy its `Modes` ArrayList and pass it to a new `Particle`